# Explaining why the determinant measures the change of volume under a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, education, volume

I would like to explain to my students that the determinant of a matrix $A$ is in fact the measure of how the volume changes under said matrix. To do that, I would like to start from the $n$-dim. cube (represented by the standard basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$) and derive the formula for the volume of the parallelepiped determined by $Ae_1,\ldots,Ae_n$. Of course, I could go to the exterior algebra $\Lambda^n(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and work there, but I don't think this would be very pedagogical...

Thus, my question is: is there a down-to-earth way to recover the determinant of $A$ as the volume of the parallelepiped defined above? And if not, how can one make a compelling argument of why taking the exterior product $Ae_1\wedge\ldots\wedge Ae_n$ gives the volume?

Comment: How do you define the volume of the parallelepiped?

Comment: How did you define the determinant of a matrix? One can define $\det(A)$ as the (signed) volume of the box built on the columns of $A$, normalized by $\det(I_n) = 1$. Linearity in each component is then natural to impose, and skew-symmetry (alternating condition) follows from the fact that if two sides are equal, then the volume should be 0. There is only one such function, and that is the determinant.

Comment: @CatalinZara Yes, I know. They know the usual formula with signs of permutations etc, and the rules to compute it. I would like to compute the volume of the parallelepiped and find the formula they already know how to compute.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Have your students ever asked you why someone would come with such a convoluted definition?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I was afraid that question would come. It all boils down to how you define the volume, of course. Personally, I would define it using the exterior algebra, but again, I don't think it would be helpful. So the idea would probably be to start from the standard cube, give it volume $1$, and then go by multilinearity on each "argument" (the vectors defining the sides), and antisymmetry under the switches. So, basically reformulate the exterior product of $n$ vectors in elementary terms... Do you know of a better approach?

Comment: @CatalinZara No, but my experience as a student is that sometimes (especially when exams are near!) you don't really try hard to understand what's going on, and just learn how to work with the objects. Comprehension comes (sometimes years) later.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Unfortunately, I don't know a better approach in general. Maybe studying the case $n=2$ with some basic geometry would help your student?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net It was my plan to start with the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$. But I'm missing a pedagogically good way to go on to treat the general case.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud  Well, maybe those students who do not try hard to understand what's going on will, for now, just accept your claim that the determinant is a volume form. Comprehension, as you said, may come later.

Comment: See https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALAPP/Peng.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred pedagogical approach is to start with examples in $2$ and $3$ dimensions.  In $2D$ we can easily see that the columns of the matrix $A$ are the vectors $\vec u= A\vec i$ and $\vec v=A \vec j$ ( where $\{\vec i, \vec j \}$ is the standard basis) and  it is easy to show that the ''signed'' area of the parallelogram with sides $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ is the cross product $ \vec u \times \vec v = \det A$.

In a similar way we can show that the mixed product of the vectors $\vec u=A\vec i$,$\vec v=A \vec j$ and $\vec w=A\vec k$ is the volume of the of the transformed parallelepiped,and these vectors are the columns of the matrix $A$ so that $\vec u\cdot(\vec v \times \vec w)=\det A$.

Now the generalization to $n-$dimensional space can be done noting the properties of the determinant, especially the multi-linearity, and noting that we can go from the volume of a $n-$cube to an $n-$polyhedron by linear tranformations of the sides.

Answer (score 1):

In 2-dimension, if you slide the side $AB$ for a parallelogram $ABCD$ along the line containing $A$ and $B$, the area remains the same. To compute the area of parallelogram $ABCD$, one can apply a shear operation to $ABCD$ and turn it into a rectangle first.

Using this sort of operation, one can show the signed-area of $ABCD$, as a function of vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$, is anti-symmetric and multi-linear. Now invite the student to express all these into linear algebra, the formula for determinant for $2 \times 2$ matrix should come up naturally.

Next, generalize this to 3-dimension. As an exercise, ask the students to compare this way of computing volume by "shearing" with how one computing determinant by elementary row (or column?) operations.